# Footer does not stay in place

Tags: css, footer

In my website, when I scroll down, the footer goes up from other object, this is really annoying, any fix?

What happens:
http://prntscr.com/2trf28

```
#end {
bottom:0;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:39px;
background-color:#00a0f0;
font-family:calibri, arial;
font-size:19px;
color:white;
}
```

CSS code: http://prntscr.com/2trgsk

Comment: You are supposed to add the code in here.

Answer (score 1):

Change `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;`

Comment: You probably have to tweek the bottom position / margin. I really can't tell you without seeing an example / code. Maybe try to reproduce in a jsFiddle.

Comment: You might also need to add some padding to the bottom of your container to keep the content from flowing behind the footer.